# How to remove Apex Parameter Prefix from Apex Parameter Name

Tags: apex

I wrote some tags like that:

```
<apex:inputText id="keyExample" />
```

After filling my inputs by some valExample and after submitting a form, I wanted to check, what is inside of Parameters Map:

```
String result;
Map<String,String> myMap = new Map<String,String>();
myMap = (Map<String,String>) ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters();
for (String key : myMap.keySet()) {
  String val = myMap.get(key);
  result = result+key+'('+val+');\n';
}
```

I see output in `result` like that:

```
(...) j_id[X1]:j_id[X2]:j_id[X3]:j_id[X4]:j_id[X5]:keyExample(valExample); (...)
```

Where `[X{1..5}]` are matched with Regex Format of `\d`.

I want to see output like that:

```
(...) keyExample(valExample); (...)
```

How can I remove this unwanted list of ids from `key`?

Comment: Not really clear what is your question.  Using `ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters()` you will get parameters that are included in the _page URL_. On the other hand the `apex:inputText` tag needs an `value` attribute linked to the apex variable. What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than removing those prefixes instead you can set them yourself to values that have more meaning (and are fixed) e.g.:

```
<apex:page id="p">
    <apex:form id="f">
       <apex:inputText id="keyExample" />
```

so that you get an ID of:

```
p:f:keyExample
```

Alternatively in your Apex you can split on the `:` and take the last part.